# How to use a function in a service in a script in html component in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular9

I'm studying angular 9 and I'm developing my first project with this technology, I have some trouble, I've put a script tag (`<script></script>`) in HTML component and I need to call a service function in this script, I know how to inject a service in a typescript file but can I use the service inside a script tag in HTML?

Comment: You don't need to use `<script>` tag in angular for calling a service.

Comment: You shoudn't use additional script tags with angular. You should import modules with import syntax.